# pandas performance:text column replacement is slow

Tags: python, pandas, list, performance

I have a large dataset with 250,000 entries, and the text column that i am processing contains a sentence is each row.

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()

df = pd.read_csv('my/huge/dataset.csv')
(e,g) -->  df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['Michael Jackson was a famous singer and songwriter.']})
```

so from text file, I am trying to find names of people and replace them with fake names from the faker library and adding the result to a new column, as follows.

```
person_list = [[n.text for n in doc.ents] for doc in nlp_news_sm.pipe(df.text.values) if [n.label_ == 'PER' for n in doc.ents]]
flat_person_list = list(set([item for sublist in person_list for item in sublist]))
fake_person_name = [fake.name() for n in range(len(flat_person_list))]
name_dict = dict(zip(flat_person_list, fake_person_name))

df.name = df.text.replace(name_dict, regex=True)
```

The problem is that it is taking forever to run and I am not sure how to enhance the performance of the code, so it can run faster.

Comment: First, try with `regex=False`. Then, how big is your replacement names dict?

Comment: Also you could rename the question to pandas text replace performance.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the peron_list has 163784 elements, so the the dict has almost the same amount of keys and also same for values
the spacy pipline also runs very slowly, i guess it is because i have used lots of list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i think i found a better way of doing text replacement in pandas, thanks to [Florian C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7373966/florin-c)'s comment.
The Spacy model still takes a lot of time, but that part I cannot change, however, instead of str.replace, i decided to use map and lambda, so now the last line is as follows:

```
df.name = df.text.map(lambda x:name_dict.get(x,x))
```